# How to enable a form field in reactive form based on previous forms value?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular form array, that kind of goes like this :

```
addNewFormRow():FormGroup{
    return this.FormBuilder.group({
      operator:new FormControl('none'),
      operatorValue:new FormControl({value : 'none', disabled : true }, Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

I have an array of form groups, where there can be more than 1 row.

By default, the newly added row will have 'operatorValue' field as disabled and I'm enabling it when the 'operator' fields value changes to anything other than 'none' (by calling a function on change of operator field).

**Problem Scenario :**
On load of the screen, I get a set of data from an object and I'm patching that value to the form.
So there will be at least five rows in which the values are present but 'operatorValue' is disabled.

**what I have tried :**

1. Manually go through the individual 'operator' form control,
2. if it's value is not none, enable the value of 'operatorValue'

This method works well in theory, but in a use case I would have different form controls that need the same kind of validation.  This is definitely not an advised method, I feel like I should add some sort of validation while initializing the form. **How would I achieve this with minimal and clean code?**

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but in terms of minimal, clean code:

****Custom Directive**** You could write a custom directive and add it to the HTML of the operatorValue FormControl. This directive, in theory, could inject NgControl, and lookup the operator FormControl via the parent property of NgControl, and handle listening to the valueChanges there. This is a little extra code, but easily maintained and clean.

****NgNeat Reactive Forms**** There’s a great library that extends Angular’s reactive form controls [here](https://github.com/ngneat/reactive-forms#disabledwhile). Using this, in the method that creates an empty form group, you could use the ‘disabledWhile’ Observable to listen to the operator FormControl and programmatically disable/enable accordingly. This adds a dependency to your project, but only adds a few lines of code to your component.

If you are only concerned about that initial load, you could also update your addNewFormRow method to take an optional parameter with the form data. Then when creating the FormGroup just use: disabled: !data.operator (instead of the hard coded true)

Comment: Thanks!, considering different possibilities, I went with the slightly modified version of your 3 suggestion